# integrate nodejs chat in codeigniter chat page

Tags: php, node.js

I am thinking to implement chat system for a social network site in nodejs. I am new to nodejs.

So my first question is:

1. Is it possible to integrate node.js only in single page of php based site?
2. Can we get php session to node.js. So we can get current session id of sender.
3. How we will handle port.

   http://domain.com/8000 to http://domain.com/chat/1002

Comment: I think you mean `http://domain.com:8000` with a colon.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a bit on this and it is not that difficult to do

For your first question yes it is I'm working on a livechat app that does that using [now.js](http://www.nowjs.com), and just included the script for now.js on the node server as a script to load.

As for sessions, you should be able to access them, though I wonder why you would need them? Now.js assigns a unique user_id for each client connected, so you can find ways of uniquely identifying clients.

For the ports, I wouldn't worry about it to much, though you can always use a proxy if you need to.

Comment: hey there! thanks for answer. ur answer clear some of my concepts. I need session as the site where I need to integrate chat is social network. userinfo are stored in mysql database. So without session how would i get user name, picture,online/offline status and location of users in chat window.